# Why do balanced Django templating {% if %} and {% endif %} get Invalid block tag on line 50: 'endif', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm getting an error specifying that an outer `{{ endif }}` close tag is not expected; `{{ empty }}` or `{{ endfor }}` is expected. That sounds like I have an `{{ endif }}` that does not match an earlier `{% if ... %}` and it expects me to close the outermost loop nestingwise (source at http://pastebin.com/Knsbi6bH). (This is intended to be within a `{{ for }}` loop, but the `{{ endif }}` AFAIK matches an opening `{{ if ... }}`. It's the `{{ endif }}` before the `</h2>`.

The reporter error is line 50:

```
40                                          {% else %}
41                                              {% if pet.shelter.website or
42                                                pet.shelter.slugline %}
43                                                  this shelter
44                                              {% endif %}
45                                          {% endif %}
46                                          {% if pet.shelter.name or
47                                            pet.shelter.website %}
48                                              </a>)
49                                          {% endif %}
50                                      {% endif %}
51                                  </h2>
52                                  {% if pet.snippet %}
53                                      {{ pet.snippet }}
54                                  {% endif %}
55                              </td>
56                          </tr>
57                      {% endif %}
58                  {% endfor %}
59              </table>
60          {% else %}
```

Pastebin is at http://pastebin.com/Knsbi6bH

Do `{% ... %}` tags need to be on a single line? I would welcome any ideas on what I am missing.

Comment: Note you have used `{{` and `}}` throughout your question instead of `{%` and `%}`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Django template tags must be on a single line

See for example [ticket #8652](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8652) (closed as wontfix), or [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/django-developers/wRKgnMIhl6g/discussion) on the django-developers mailing list.

You need to change tags like

```
{% if pet.shelter.name or 
    pet.shelter.website %}
```

to

```
{% if pet.shelter.name or pet.shelter.website %}
```